# Can Entity Framework CF store 'object type' values?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

it's a question.

I need to store props for my objects. And I do not know - what kind of prop it is - it's data driven.
I use 'object type' for 'value' of prop, but... Will EF work with object type?

Object is never complex type - it's Boolean,String,Int and Guid.

Until EF steps in the game - all was OK.

Thanks.

Comment: Just store both the type and the value in their string representation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. EF doesn't support this because it would require "dynamic" column type in the database. Database can support such scenario - for example SQL server offers `sql_variant`. Unfortunately EF cannot map these columns. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137509/Reading-sql_variant-in-Entity-Framework) is workaround for using variant column in read only scenarios. The workaround uses `DefiningQuery` in EDMX. In theory you should be able to map modification commands as well to be able to use it for saving changes. It is not possible to use it in code first - code first offers only basic mapping.